# Blackberry ad-banner click

Tags: blackberry

How to add click event in blackberry banner ad.
Here is my code:

```
public class DemonstrationScreen extends MainScreen 
{  
    public DemonstrationScreen()
    {
      final Bitmap customPlaceholder = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("arrow.png");
      Banner bannerAd = new Banner(add.APID,null,10000, customPlaceholder);
      bannerAd.setMMASize(Banner.MMA_SIZE_EXTRA_LARGE);
      VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager
                                 (VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL
                                 | VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR
                                 | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
      HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager
                                 (HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER
                                 | HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_VCENTER);
      hfm.add(bannerAd);
      vfm.add(hfm);
      add(vfm);

      FieldChangeListener listener=new FieldChangeListener() {
            public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

                if(field==bannerAd){
                    Dialog.alert("Banner clicked");
                }
            }};
            bannerAd.setChangeListener(listener);

    }  
}
```

this is not working. when i click the ad, then its not showing anythig.

Answer (score 1):

I do think this is unexpected/improper usage of `Banner`.

However you could potentially do this by overriding `navigationClick()` at `Banner`:

```
public class DemonstrationScreen extends MainScreen 
{  
    public DemonstrationScreen()
    {
      final Bitmap customPlaceholder = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("arrow.png");
      Banner bannerAd = new Banner(add.APID,null,10000, customPlaceholder) {
          protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
              Dialog.alert("Banner clicked");
              return super.navigationClick(status, time);
          }
      };
      bannerAd.setMMASize(Banner.MMA_SIZE_EXTRA_LARGE);
      VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager
                                 (VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL
                                 | VerticalFieldManager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR
                                 | VerticalFieldManager.USE_ALL_WIDTH);
      HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager
                                 (HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_HCENTER
                                 | HorizontalFieldManager.FIELD_VCENTER);
      hfm.add(bannerAd);
      vfm.add(hfm);
      add(vfm);
    }  
}
```

But since RIM made `Banner` class final you can not do this. So I think your request has no simple solution. A hard solution would be to "figure out" what field is clicked at the `MainScreen` level (in `navigationClick` of `MainScreen` you can check what field is in focus and do smth).

Comment: we cant add overriding navigationClick() at Banner.i just give the focus to the bannerad. bannerAd.setFocusOverrideFlag(true);  its not working. so how to implement it ?